# How to pre-authorize URL to use microphone in Electron (or Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, electron

I need to pre-authorize a URL to use microphone. It's an internal system accessed via Electron (v4.1.3).

Pre-authorization is required as users use it in some sort of Linux thin client. That is, each day the system bootstrap from an image and then profiles,etc are created. Therefore users would have to click Yes on the access prompt every single day, and if hitting NO just causing headaches to provide them steps to fix as the system requires mic/audio.

I've checked Google Chrome, and apparently it writes the permission on `{chrome_profile_dir}\Default\Preferences` file.

But on Electron, could not see same behavior on `AppData\Roaming\{app.name}\Preferences` file. So, to be honest I don't even know where Electron is storing the permission. I deleted the aforementioned folder, but it doesn't ask permission anymore.

Is there a way, like writing to a preference file, I could pre-authorize this? If yes, would write that to the image file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use permission request handlers in electron.
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session#sessetpermissionrequesthandlerhandler